Apache читает только первую строку .htaccess
У меня есть файл .htaccess с текстом
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex default.html

Проблема в том, что при загрузке сайта default.html не загружается, и когда я попробовал написать так:
DirectoryIndex default.html
RewriteEngine On

То сайт начал загружаться, но все последующие правила - нет. Причем даже если первая строка будет комментарием - последующие также не загружаются. Что можно сделать? Заранее спасибо.

Какая кодировка у файла? Каким редактором редактируете файл? Попробуйте сохранить файл как UTF без BOM

@AndrewHobbit кодировка UTF-8, редактирую через nano, попробую на всякий пересоздать файл и скопировать туда содержимое.

Ошибка была в кодировке. В Unix используется перенос строки вида \n, а в MacOS - \r, из за чего читалась только первая строка. Решение - попросту скопировать содержимое файла, пересоздать его и вставить обратно уже с нужной кодировкой.
